# Could Redux hypothetically infer the type of mapStateToProps passed to it?

Tags: typescript, redux

If i connect my component like so:

`connect(({ users }) => ({ users }))(MyComponent)`

Typescript will give me an error saying `type {} does not contain a property users`, but I would imagine it could infer the type of mapStateToProps to be the `ReturnType<typeof reducer>` where reducer is the function i gave my store.

Is there any way redux could be changed so my above code doesn't error with typescript? Or am i misunderstanding something regarding `Typescript` or `react-redux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TS can't magically infer that, because the definition of that function is completely separate from your store.  (In fact, technically that definition could be used with *any* store that happens to have a `state.users` property, regardless of what the rest of the state's contents look like.)

So yes, the best approach is to do `type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>`, import that type into your connected components, and declare the `state` argument as being a `RootState`.  I showed that general approach in the [Redux Starter Kit "Advanced Tutorial" page](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial).  That page shows using the `RootState` type with our `useSelector` hook, but the same approach would apply for `connect`.

Comment: But it's in the brackets... so close to the text of the function. Surely the number of characters close it is would allow it to infer! I'm just kidding. What you suggested makes perfect sense, thanks.